# Regex for transform data formats

Tags: regex

I have data from yahoo finance such as:

Format 1:

```
2015-07-29,5006.009766,5021.439941,4970.279785,5017.439941,118376700,5017.439941
```

I need to transform these data into the fallowing format:

Format 2:

```
DJIA 20150730 0.5352534
```

where the 1st row is name, which I will give, 2nd row is the date in format YYYYMMDD, and the 3rd row is the data from the 5th row in the above data format.

Can someone tell me how can I transform the data from Format 1 into format 2?

Thank you very very much!

Regards

Comment: `0.5352534` appears nowhere in your input row.

Comment: Yes, that is right, it is just an example, a bad one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}),[^,]+,([^.]+)\.([^,]+),.+
```

for the match, and the pattern

```
DJIA $1$2$3 0.$4$5
```

for substitution.

See working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sF7pA0/1).